# How to upload file into server using smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I've written code for upload file to server like below.

Home.tpl

```
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_file.php"  >
     <label for="file">Filename:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
```

upload_file.php

```
     if(($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0))
     {
      $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];//the files name takes from the HTML form
      $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];//file in the PHP tmp folder
      $fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];//the type of file 
      $fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];//file size in bytes
      $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file"]["error"];//0 for false and 1 for true
      $target_path = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 

      $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $target_path);
     }
```

But i getting 'Undefined index: file' error. please help me to get rid from there.

Comment: When are you getting 'Undefined index: file' error ?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` first in your `upload_file.php` and check if that looks anything like you expect it to look.

Comment: @Martinperry : when execution reach that line 'if(($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0))'. i got here.

Comment: You don't look like you're doing a lot of error checking.  You're not bothering to check the value of the error field, for a start.  When dealing with user input (which is what a file upload is) you can't be caviller about verifying the data they've sent you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error every time, its because you dont have set variable $_FILES. That variable is set only after you submit your form.

In that case, to get rid of error mesage, add control of variable:

```
if((isset($_FILES["file"])) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0))
```

Comment: i used like what you said but i dint get any error. but script not running.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. If there is no error, than script must run, if you call it

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if(($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0))
```

to

```
if((isset($_FILES["file"]["size"]) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0))
```

Comment: i used like what you said but i dint get any error. but script not running

Answer (score 0):

i think its $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0] for the first file. 
check it with var_dump($_FILES); or print_r($_FILES) 
then iterate throu it with an foreach. something like

```
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    //...
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"][$arr]); 
}
```

Comment: Thats not right. There is no $_FILES["file"]["name"][0] for multiple files. [0] will give first character of name (but I am not sure if also in PHP)